# Replace codeline with file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Is it possible to change a line of PHP code by file_get_contents and str_replace?

Example (origin code):

```
redirect(href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_SHIPPING, '', 'SSL'));
```

change to:

```
redirect(href_link(FILENAME_ACCOUNT, '', 'SSL'));
```

The reason for the question is, that I don't want to change any sourcecode.

Comment: Though it is possible - it is a __very bad__ idea

Comment: I know it is a very bad idea, but I don't want to change the original code